# Angular http.post() Syntax Issues with body

Tags: angular, api, postman, http-post

This is the Postman Screenshot by which I'm getting response successfully! And I want to fetch data in angular but the `http.post()` syntax issue occurs.

[image: See here]

```
const bodyCode = { seat_hell: "765", helloo: "1611255600" };

export class DashDataTable22Component implements  OnInit {

  data =[]; 
  
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.http.post('http://199.100.155.771/xyzza/', JSON.stringify(bodyCode)).subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.data = data.json(); 

      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bodyCode` without stringify.

```
this.http.post('http://199.100.155.771/xyzza/', bodyCode)
.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data.json(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kshitij, I have also tried like this but same issue.

Comment: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: try `this.http.post('http://199.100.155.771/xyzza/', JSON.parse(bodyCode))`